# javascript div class variable sum or add math

Tags: javascript

```
<span class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function totall(){
 var sum = parseInt(simpleCart_grandTotal.value);
if(parseInt(sum.value))
        totall += parseFloat(sum) *20;
});
$('#totall').text( +totall); }
</script>
<div class="totall"></div>
```

i want simpleCart_grandTotal class value multiply by 20 the result become div class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function totall(){
 var sum = $('.vote-count-post').text()
if(Number($('.vote-count-post').text()) == $('.vote-count-post').text())
        $('.totall').text( Number(sum) + Number($('.totall').text()) )
});}
</script>
<div class="totall"></div>
```

Comment: oh! you got his question?

Comment: yeah !! description and the code he has written is not proper . I corrected it and replied on my answer.

Comment: my question is class have number value how do fix this???
<span class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></span>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = $('.simpleCart_grandTotal').text();
var y = 2;
var z = x * y;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
</script>